# What is the proper way to use tkinter grid() across several classes all posting widgets to the main window?

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to learn tkinter and specifically to understand how grid() works across classes.  I found this simple code from a post several years ago using pack().  What changes would have to be made to this code to use grid() instead of pack()?  I assume this is simple but I have not been able to create the LabelFrame widgets using grid().

```
import tkinter as tk

class Testing(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        self.buttonWidth = 10
        self.parent=parent
        self.main = main 

        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, text="Test Operations",
            padx=10,
            pady=10
        )

        self.taskButton = tk.Button(self, text="Do A Task", 
            width=self.buttonWidth,
            command=self.doATask,
        )

        self.taskButton.pack()

    def doATask(self):
        self.main.results.getResult()

class Results(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        self.parent = parent
        self.main = main 
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, text="Visual Results")

        self.resultLbl = tk.Label(self, text="Result")
        self.resultLbl.pack()

    def getResult(self):
        self.resultLbl.config(bg='yellow')

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)

        self.testing = Testing(self.parent, self)
        self.results = Results(self.parent, self)

        self.testing.pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.results.pack(fill=tk.X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Modular GUI App")
    Application(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should try using `grid` instead of `pack`, and then ask questions after you've done some experimentation.

Comment: replace `pack()` with `grid()`

Comment: @masque Well, that was too simple... I had deleted all pack() statements and started from scratch trying to use grid() with limited success.  I see more clearly how it is working now.  Thanks.

Comment: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/layout-mgt.html is mostly about using grid.